# Are you sure you want to navigate?

Tags: javascript

What is the JavaScript code/event(s) that is used by sites like stackoverflow and Gmail to test for the user exiting the page once they have begun editing and try to navigate away?

```
"Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The event used is called `onbeforeunload`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="foo"></input>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function unloadMessage() {
            return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
        }

        function setConfirmUnload(enabled) {
            window.onbeforeunload = enabled ? unloadMessage : null;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#foo").keypress(function() {
                setConfirmUnload(true);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remember `window.onbeforeunload` doesn't work in Opera, users will just navigate away, without warning.

Comment: Are you sure it's $("#foo").change?
It looks like change doesn't take effect until the field has lost the focus.

Comment: You're right, it makes more sense to handle `keypress` instead of `change`. I updated my answer.

Comment: You may want to remove the keypress event listener after it has been triggered the first time.  As is, setConfirmUnload is getting called for every keypress.

Answer (score 3):

[onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event.  Mozilla provides useful example code.  you just want to have a function that:

1. Returns a string
2. Sets e.returnValue to that string, where e is the argument or window.event.

The string will be used as your custom message.