# How do i turn off the message warning there are unsaved changes on this form.

Tags: javascript, warnings

How do i turn off the message warning there are unsaved changes on this form. i see how to turn it on but somewhere it has already been turned on within the coding.  i don't want the users to see this on our web application, i want them to be able to navigate around without any warnings anywhere.

Comment: show your code,what have you tried till now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are you sure you want to navigate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331155/are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate)

Answer (score 0):

Add script to bottom of the page:

`window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {};`

It can help you.